# Adding additional label to term using javascript

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, office-365, taxonomy

I am trying to add a label to a term using the following code:

```
    var taxonomyContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var taxonomySession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(taxonomyContext);
    var termStores = taxonomySession.get_termStores();
    var termStore = termStores.getByName("TaxonomyName");
    var projectNumberTermSet = termStore.getTermSet("termsetid");

    var term = projectNumberTermSet.getTerm("theguid");

    taxonomyContext.load(term);

    var newLabel = term.createLabel("new label name", 1033, false);

    taxonomyContext.load(newLabel);

    taxonomyContext.executeQueryAsync(successHandler, errorHandler);
```

The following error is returned:

> Could not complete cross-domain call: Access denied. You do not have
>   permission to perform this action or access this resource.

I am able to successfully add terms to the same termstore via javascript, so not sure how it can actually be a permissions problem.

The platform is Office 365.

The code is running in a sharepoint-hosted app.

Anyone come across this issue before?

Answer (score 2):

On SP On-premises, your code doesn't work anymore. So I guess, that's really not a permission problem. Please find below the code which is working on my machine :

```
function addNewLabel(){
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var taxonomySession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);
        var termStore = taxonomySession.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
        var termSets = termStore.getTermSetsByName("Language", 1033);
        var termSet = termSets.getByName("Language");
        var terms = termSet.getAllTerms();
        context.load(terms);
        context.executeQueryAsync(function onSuccess() {
            var term = terms.get_data()[0];
            var newLabel = term.createLabel("new label name", 1033, false);
            context.load(newLabel);
            context.executeQueryAsync(function onSuccess(){
            }, function onFailure(args) {
                alert('Error: '+args);
            });
        }, function onFailure(args) {
            alert('Error: '+args);
        });
    }
```

I'm loading all terms for a specific termset and taking the first one to pass a new label. There are two different async calls, that's maybe your error.

Regards,